# Karma callback is always undefined

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I am facing an issue during unit testing of my service
this is my test case

```
it("updateUserProfile() should update user profile", async(() => {
 mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
 let responseOpts = new ResponseOptions({ body: JSON.stringify({ username: "testuser" }) });
  connection.mockRespond(new Response(responseOpts));
 });
 let obj = {
  callback: (r) => {
    expect(r.username).toBe("testuser");
  }
 };
 spyOn(obj, "callback").and.callThrough();
 service.updateUserProfile({}, obj.callback);
 expect(obj.callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

and this my service

```
updateUserProfile(user: Profile, callback?: Function): void {
 let sub = this.http.patch(url, user, { headers: this.getHeaders() }).subscribe(r => {
   callback(r);
   if (sub) sub.unsubscribe();
 });
}
```

in this case it is working fine my `spy` is is returning true that callback is been fired but the code inside my `callback` is always undefined I want to test the response as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the problem's solution

```
updateUserProfile(user: Profile, callback?: Function): void {
 let sub = this.http.patch(url, user, { headers: this.getHeaders() }).subscribe(r => {
   callback(r.json());
   if (sub) sub.unsubscribe();
 });
}
```

I was calling `callback` without parsing response into json somehow it should atleast call my `callback` with response. after changing `callback(r)` to `callback(r.json())` I got the data into my callback.